# Create named object

Tags: python

I see that there is `add_named` function which allows to create me a named object. There is also a `mesh.primitive_cube_add`, which allows me to create a cube mesh object. How can I combine them to create a named cube mesh?

Comment: Can you provide a link to `add_named` method.  After a call to a mesh.primitive_*_add operator, in object mode, the newly created object will be `ob = context.active_object` `ob.name="NEWNAME"`

Comment: @batFINGER It [comes](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_57_release/bpy.ops.object.html) right after object.addobject.addobject.add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
ob.name = 'CUBEOBJ'
me.name = 'CUBEMESH'
```